# Print Nested Json in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am creating a simple Json and PHP MCQ quiz game. In which i have created a json file. In .json  all the question are written like mentioned below. 
I am able to just simply print a data of json ....but what i am stuck at is 
I want the question choices print with radio button at front and only one can be selected. Like a proper mcq game.

i have tried doing this

```
    echo "<p>". $value['question'].

        "<pre>".implode("<input type='radio'>",$value['answerChoices'])."</pre>

        </p>";

}
```

but in this there is a bug that i can click on all radio button and as we know we shoul only be able to click on one per question.

this is json

```
[

      {
          "number": 1,
          "question": "Eighteen thousandths, written as a decimal, is:",
          "answers": [
              "0.0018",
              "0.018",
              "0.18"
          ],
          "correct_answer": 1
      },
      {
          "number": 2,
          "question": "The next number in the sequence <b>1, 3, 6, 10, </b> is:",
          "answers": [
              "12",
              "13",
              "14",
              "15"
          ],
          "correct_answer": 4
      }
  ]
```

this is php

```
$string = file_get_contents("example_10.json");
$json_data = json_decode($string, true);

print_r ($json_data);
print_r ($json_data["SSC"][0]["question"]); 
foreach ($json_data as $key => $value) {

    echo "<p>". $value['question'].

        "<pre>".implode("<input type='radio'>",$value['answerChoices'])."</pre>

        </p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Add a name tag in radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to select only one radio button, you need to give them the same name attribute. That makes them belong in the same group. You could do something like

`"<input type='radio' name='question" . $value['number'] . "'>"`

Comment: I added the question number to the name attribute so that the radio buttons of each question would have different names. Sorry but I don't want to go to your Google Drive to look at the picture.

Comment: sorry .... actually i had to post this comment as a reply to to the person commented on post. Sorry

Comment: your answer solved my problem thankyou @radulfr. But only one error i am getting ....the first option of very first question is not getting its radio button

Comment: this is the output with an error 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=18e76-K6jMWQ7NSpbvIUWZ3dBa3AzD_xB

Comment: implode adds the given string between the array elements. You can either add the missing radio button to the beginning, or use a loop instead of implode.

Comment: so is there any way to print json data in correct format of question with option

Comment: What i mean is name is diffrent for all the question and its working fine. But how would i able to give every option a diffrent value so that after the user submit particular radio answer . I can compare it with answer of the question

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a , before $value?

```
"<pre>".implode("<input type='radio'>",$value['answerChoices'])."</pre>
```

You need to replace it with . to concatenate.

```
"<pre>".implode("<input type='radio'>".$value['answerChoices'])."</pre>
```